# Unity GameJoly API not working

Tags: c#, api, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use the GameJolt API for Unity, and as soon as I try to use

```
GameJolt.UI.Manager.Instance.ShowSignIn ();
```

It gives me this:

[image: Error]

Here is the code for `Manager.cs`:

```
using GameJolt.UI.Controllers;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

namespace GameJolt.UI
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]
    public class Manager : GameJolt.API.Core.MonoSingleton<Manager>
    {
        #region Init
        SignInWindow signinWindow;
        TrophiesWindow trophiesWindow;
        LeaderboardsWindow leaderboardsWindow;
        Behaviours.NotificationCentre notificationCentre;

        override protected void Init()
        {
            var animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
            notificationCentre = animator.GetBehaviour<Behaviours.NotificationCentre>();

            // GetComponentInChildren does not look in inactive childrens.
            // GetComponentsInChildren does look in inactive children but would alocate memory.
            // Instead, looping over childrens for what we need.
            foreach (Transform children in transform)
            {
                if (signinWindow == null)
                {
                    signinWindow = children.GetComponent<SignInWindow>();
                    if (signinWindow != null)
                    {
                        signinWindow.Init(animator);
                    }
                }

                if (trophiesWindow == null)
                {
                    trophiesWindow = children.GetComponent<TrophiesWindow>();
                    if (trophiesWindow != null)
                    {
                        trophiesWindow.Init(animator);
                    }
                }

                if (leaderboardsWindow == null)
                {
                    leaderboardsWindow = children.GetComponent<LeaderboardsWindow>();
                    if (leaderboardsWindow != null)
                    {
                        leaderboardsWindow.Init(animator);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion Init

        #region SignIn
        public void ShowSignIn()
        {
            ShowSignIn(null);
        }

        public void ShowSignIn(Action<bool> callback)
        {
            signinWindow.Show(callback);
        }
        #endregion SignIn

        #region Trophies
        public void ShowTrophies()
        {
            ShowTrophies(null);
        }

        public void ShowTrophies(Action<bool> callback)
        {
            trophiesWindow.Show(callback);
        }
        #endregion Trophies

        #region Leaderboards
        public void ShowLeaderboards()
        {
            ShowLeaderboards(null);
        }

        public void ShowLeaderboards(Action<bool> callback)
        {
            leaderboardsWindow.Show(callback);
        }
        #endregion Leaderboards

        #region Notifications
        public void QueueNotification(string text)
        {
            var notification = new Objects.Notification(text);
            QueueNotification(notification);
        }

        public void QueueNotification(string text, Sprite image)
        {
            var notification = new Objects.Notification(text, image);
            QueueNotification(notification);
        }

        public void QueueNotification(Objects.Notification notification)
        {
            notificationCentre.QueueNotification(notification);
        }
        #endregion Notidications
    }
}
```

And here is my code for `Menu.cs`:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections;

public class Menu : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        GameJolt.API.SessionStatus
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void StartGame() {
        SceneManager.LoadScene ("level1");
    }

    public void Quit() {
        Application.Quit ();
    }

    public void Settings() {


    }

    public void Credits() {
        SceneManager.LoadScene ("Credits");
    }

    public void MainMenu() {
        SceneManager.LoadScene ("Main Menu");
    }
}
```

I have looked up the error in Google, but have come up with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object` - you are trying to access an object that has not been defined yet. Look on the lines the error is on, and see what object is being referenced. It hasn't been set yet.

Comment: Looking at the first error, it says there isn't an instance of `Gamejolt.API.Manager`. Double check that you have that in the game scene.